# getActualMaximum() GregorianCalendar from Java to c#

Tags: c#

How do i get Actual Maximum from day of year in c# ?

```
GregorianCalendar calendar;
calendar.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: You mean the maximum possible value that field can take, i.e. 366 for DAY_OF_YEAR? So you're asking if there's a C# equivalent to the Java .getActualMaximum?

Comment: This code is in Java. I want to get it in c#

Answer (score 1):

There isn't, as far as I can see, a direct replacement for Java's Calendar.getActualMaximum. Here's the C# [reference source for GregorianCalendar](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/gregoriancalendar.cs,cc2b088f539805ca): you can see there's no 366 constant or any method that would return it..

You haven't told us what you're doing with the number, but

1. if you need the number of days in a specific year then you can use [GetDaysInYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getdaysinyear?view=netframework-4.8):

   ```
   int maximum_day_of_year = calendar.GetDaysInYear(2020);
   ```
2. if you need the maximum in general then assuming this will always be a GregorianCalendar you'll just have to hard-code 366:

   ```
   private const int MAXIMUM_DAY_OF_YEAR = 366;
   ```

Comment: GregorianCalendar reference source I mean it Java not c#

Comment: I linked to the C# GregorianCalendar class (which I assume you're using?) source to show that there's no equivalent method.